# SQL Server 2016 Install - R Server and R Services Install Failed

Tags: sql-server, r

I just installed SQL Server 2016 Developer and included R Server and R Services to get installed as well. Everything installed correctly except the R Server and R Services. The log file contained this:

```
2016-07-29T17:07:39 INFO    Command invoked: D:\x64\RSetup.exe /install /component SRS /version 8.0.3 /language 1033 /destdir C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\R_SERVICES /logfile C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20160729_125230\RSetup.log /instance MSSQLSERVER
2016-07-29T17:07:39 INFO    Using default cache dir: C:\Users\fs103799\AppData\Local\Temp\
2016-07-29T17:07:39 INFO    Backing up source dir: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\R_SERVICES\ => C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\R_SERVICES_63975911-f850-4ad1-bf7c-21adf0f9ba6d
2016-07-29T17:07:39 ERROR   Error renaming source dir: Access to the path 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\R_SERVICES\' is denied.
2016-07-29T17:07:39 INFO    Exiting with code 5
```

I have no idea why the access to the path was denied. The path exists and there are files there. So the install process was able to store files there, but then couldn't access the folder.

Comment: I vaguely remembered reading somewhere that you will encounter errors if you try to install both R server and R service at the SAME time. But it is fine if you install one first and then another.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3a2a99d2-33de-42c1-a855-79da91ebeb69/error-installing-sql-server-2016-r-services?forum=SQLServer2016Preview

Comment: @JasonB. - Thank you but that link isn't particulary useful. And it doesn't apply to the shipping version of SQL Server 2016.

Comment: Check: If that folder exists; If account you are using for installation can write to that folder; If Account you use for "R" has full rights for that service.

Answer (score 1):

Add the SQLRUsergroup to the LogOnLocally user right assignment. You might have to create the SQLRUsergroup if it does not already exist. Ensure the logon used to execute setup is a local admin on the box.

Answer (score 1):

Refering to this page [Install SQL Server 2016 R Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/install/sql-r-services-windows-install?view=sql-server-2016) (Microsoft | SQL Docs) 
it clearly states in step 3.:

> **Important**
>   Do not install R Server and R Services at the same time.